# Which positive integer is equal to it's own Scrabble score when spelt out in full?

Tags: code-golf, string

The Challenge: Make the shortest program to confirm that 12 is the answer.

(The puzzle is from Ian Stewart's "Cabinet of Mathematical Curiosities". 
This is my first code golf question. I hope this type of thing is allowed)

In Scrabble the following are the letter scores:
AEIOULNRST score 1 each
DG          score 2 each
BCMP        score 3 each
FHVWY       score 4 each
K           scores 5
JX          score 8 each
QX          score 10 each.

Comment: I would remove the answer from the description and add some rules. Like hard coding is not allowed etc. Also might be fun if people can find other things. Perhaps its possible that the score and the number(digits) are palindrome (and numbers consist of more than 2 digits.

Comment: Very similar to [Determine a string's Scrabbe score and validity](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35741/14215).

Comment: @Geobits I see what you mean but just because they both have to do with scrable and the score don't make it a duplicate in my opinion. He did ask for something specific which doesn't happen in the question you posted. As I see it the focus in the other question lies in validating the word which isn't the case here.

Comment: @TeunPronk My point is that (as it stands now), you could just use input `"twelve"` to those answers and compare it to `12` to "confirm that 12 is the answer". This one is unclearly written, but I'd retract if it's given a good spec that better distinguishes it from the other.

Comment: @Geobits True, but that would make any BF question a duplicate to the one where you had to make a BF generator/intepretor. I partially agree with you, the challenge needs some editing but I do think it's unique enough compared to the other one.

Comment: @TeunPronk My close vote was for unclear, not duplicate. I mentioned the other one in comments so that any editor wouldn't unknowingly *make* it an exact duplicate.

Comment: `SIX AND TWENTY` = `TWENTY AND SIX` = `26`

Comment: @Geobits IX if roman numerals are allowed. Questions that need to write "no hardcoding the answer" always run into problems, as it's difficult to define what constitutes hardcoding. I think making it a search for other numbers would make a much better question, but as demonstrated by these examples, allowable spellings must be clearly specified. I think allowing blank tiles would increase the number of hits a lot (but only 2 as in the scrabble set, not infinite because then you could do anything.) Upvoting and closevoting. Donagh, check out http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/15599

Comment: @TeunPronk Thanks for helpful comments. I included the answer because I thought as a programming challenge it is way below the capacity of any programmer worth his salt.I am working on a way to refine the question.

Comment: @steveverill Thanks for upvote. I was not aware of meta.codegolf per se. Thanks for the pointer. How to proceed? Should I remove the question from here and ask it in [link]meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com instead? n00b apologises for ignorance.

Comment: @DonaghMcCarthy Post your question as an answer to this one: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges Then you can get input and feedback on it. I don't know if you're supposed to edit and re-open this question, or delete it and post a new one. You can leave it up for now, and edit in a link to your sandbox post on the meta site. i.e. `This question is being discussed on the sandbox here (link)`

Comment: Either try and solve the problem here, or delete and repost in the sandbox (then when it's fixed you can delete and post back here). Don't do both. I think sandbox is the best place because there are quite big issues with this question. Even allowing for some flexibility, the number of hits is going to be small, which makes the question vulnerable to hardcoded answers. Throwing an idea out: I suggest the user might enter a number (in figures)between 0 and 999 (or 999999) and the program would output the scrabble score for that number. Use of `a` `and` & `one` with 100 would need clarification.

Comment: @steveverrill That's a good reply. I will delete and re-post in sandbox. Your suggestion regarding user input is well made - I had the same idea myself later. As a n00b, it was a bit hairy having those heavy hitters pounce on my question before I had a chance to examine it on screen. Their vigilance is commendable.

Comment: Another idea for user input might be to have them input numbers `n,m`, and find all integers up to `m` with score `n`.

Comment: @Geobits - yep, that would certainly make the challenge more interesting. I will see what I can do to incorporate it. Originally I brought the puzzle in verbatim but it is not perhaps interesting enough for the programming fraternity as it stands. I think I get it.